# Check for existing conda environment in Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, anaconda, conda

I am creating a conda environment inside a Makefile. However, if this environment was created already, I'd like to skip that step. How can I check the following:

1. Is there already an environment with that name? Would simple directory check suffice?
2. Is this environment already activated? Optional. It does not hurt if env is activated twice, I think.

```
CONDA_ENV_NAME := myname

ifeq (,$(shell which conda))
    HAS_CONDA=False
else
    HAS_CONDA=True
    CONDA_ACTIVATE=source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate ; conda activate
endif

environment:
ifeq (True,$(HAS_CONDA))
    @echo ">>> Detected conda, creating conda environment."
    ## Here I'd like to check if this environment already exists
    conda env create -f environment.yml -n $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
    ## ... and if the env should be activated (optional)
    $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
else
    @echo ">>> Install conda first."
endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following:

```
ifeq (,$(shell which conda))
    HAS_CONDA=False
else
    HAS_CONDA=True
    ENV_DIR=$(shell conda info --base)
    MY_ENV_DIR=$(ENV_DIR)/envs/$(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
    CONDA_ACTIVATE=source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate ; conda activate
endif

environment:
ifeq (True,$(HAS_CONDA))
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(MY_ENV_DIR))","") # check if the directory is there
    @echo ">>> Found $(CONDA_ENV_NAME) environment in $(MY_ENV_DIR). Skipping installation..."
else
    @echo ">>> Detected conda, but $(CONDA_ENV_NAME) is missing in $(ENV_DIR). Installing ..."
    conda env create -f environment.yml -n $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
endif
else
    @echo ">>> Install conda first."
    exit
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script `activate.sh` (run it as `source ./activate.sh` or `. ./activate.sh`)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

ENV_NAME="<your env name>"

RED='\033[1;31m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
CYAN='\033[1;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

if ! (return 0 2>/dev/null) ; then
    # If return is used in the top-level scope of a non-sourced script,
    # an error message is emitted, and the exit code is set to 1
    echo
    echo -e $RED"This script should be sourced like"$NC
    echo "    . ./activate.sh"
    echo
    exit 1  # we detected we are NOT source'd so we can use exit
fi

if type conda 2>/dev/null; then
    if conda info --envs | grep ${ENV_NAME}; then
      echo -e $CYAN"activating environment ${ENV_NAME}"$NC
    else
      echo
      echo -e $RED"(!) Please install the conda environment ${ENV_NAME}"$NC
      echo
      return 1  # we are source'd so we cannot use exit
    fi
else
    echo
    echo -e $RED"(!) Please install anaconda"$NC
    echo
    return 1  # we are source'd so we cannot use exit
fi

conda activate ${ENV_NAME}
```