# Check if conda env exists and create if not in bash

Tags: python, bash, conda

I have a build script to run a simple python app. I am trying to set it up that it will run for any user that has conda installed and in their PATH. No other prerequisites. I have that pretty much accomplished but would like to make it more efficient for returning users.

build_run.sh

```
conda init bash
conda env create --name RUN_ENV --file ../run_env.yml -q --force
conda activate RUN_ENV
python run_app.py
conda deactivate
```

I would like to make it that the script checks if RUN_ENV already exists and activates it instead of forcing its creation every time. I tried

```
ENVS=$(conda env list | awk '{print }' )
if [[ conda env list = *"RUN_ENV"* ]]; then
   conda activate RUN_ENV
else 
   conda env create --name RUN_ENV --file ../run_env.yml -q
   conda activate RUN_ENV
   exit
fi;
python run_app.py
conda deactivate
```

but it always came back as false and tried to create RUN_ENV

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115420/check-for-existing-conda-environment-in-makefile Hope this helps

Comment: i would love to help. there are a couple of issues i see right off the bat, but i haven't used conda. if you don't mind could you please update your answer with output of `conda env list`? i am not quite sure what you're trying to test in your `if` construct

Comment: A better design would be to use a prefix (`--prefix, -p`) to install the environment relative to where the app is installed, rather than using a named environment (`--name, -n`). This mitigates against potential name collisions and would avoid having to query the user's existing environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update 2022**

i've been receiving upvotes recently. so i'm going to bump up that this method overall is not natively "conda" and might not be the best approach. like i said originally, i do not use conda. take my advice at your discretion.

rather, please refer to [@merv's comment in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597896/check-if-conda-env-exists-and-create-if-not-in-bash/70598193#comment124799776_70597896) suggesting the use of the `--prefix` flag

additionally take a look at the [documentation for further details](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Target%20Environment%20Specification)

NOTE: you can always use a function within your bash script for repeated command invocations with very specific flags

e.g

```bash
function PREFIXED_CONDA(){
   action=${1};
   # copy $1 to $action;
   shift 1;
   # delete first argument and shift remaining indeces to the left
   conda ${action} --prefix /path/to/project ${@}
}
```

---

i am not sure how `conda env list` works (i don't use Anaconda); and your current `if`-tests are vague

but i'm going out on a limb and *guessing* this is what you're looking for

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ...
find_in_conda_env(){
    conda env list | grep "${@}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}

if find_in_conda_env ".*RUN_ENV.*" ; then
   conda activate RUN_ENV
else 
# ...
```

instead of bringing it out into a separate function, you could also do

```
# ...
if conda env list | grep ".*RUN_ENV.*" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
# ...
```

bonus points for neatness and clarity if you use [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

```
# ...
if { conda env list | grep 'RUN_ENV'; } >/dev/null 2>&1; then
# ...
```

`if` simply checks the [exit code](https://www.shellscript.sh/exitcodes.html#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20GNU%20grep%20returns%200%20on%20success%2C%201%20if%20no%20matches%20were%20found%2C%20and%202%20for%20other%20errors). and `grep` exits with `0` (success) as long as there's at least one match of the pattern provided; this evaluates to "true" in the `if` statement

(`grep` would match and succeed even if the pattern is just 'RUN_ENV' ;) )

---

the `awk` portion of `ENVS=$(conda env list | awk '{print }' )` does virtually nothing. i would expect the output to be in tabular format, but `{print }` does no filtering, i believe you were looking for `{print $n}` where `n` is a column number or `awk /PATTERN/ {print}` where PATTERN is likely `RUN_ENV` and only lines which have PATTERN are printed.

but even so, storing a table in a string variable is going to be messing. you might want an [array](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays).

then coming to your `if`-condition, it's plain syntactically wrong.

- the `[[` construct is for comparing *values*: integer, string, regex
- but here on the left of `=` we have a command `conda env list`

  - which i believe is also the contents of `$ENVS`
- hence we can assume you meant `[[ "${ENVS}" == *"RUN_ENV"* ]]`

  - or alternately `[[ $(conda env list) == *"RUN_ENV"* ]]`
- but still, regex matching against a table... not very intuitive imo
- but it works... sort of
- the proper clean syntax for regex matching is

  - `[[ ${value} =~ /PATTERN/ ]]`

Comment: `conda env list` just prints to the console all environments currently stored in ./Miniconda3/envs/ which is the default dir that envs are stored for Andacona and what is checked when creating new ones. I was using based off another post I found here

Comment: hi @cdub i was wondering more wrt to the output format. but i believe using grep as i did in my answer will work out just fine for you. could you try it out and let me know if it works a you expect? also take heed of [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597896/check-if-conda-env-exists-and-create-if-not-in-bash/70598193#comment124799776_70597896) from someone actually uses Anaconda for a different matter in you script :)

Comment: Your solution worked great. I am currently looking at @merv `-p` suggestion to see if it is more conda efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I made the following script:

```
if conda info --envs | grep -q base; then echo "base already exists"; else conda create -y -n base; fi
```

Where `base` is the name of your env.

Comment: could anyone explain to me why "if [ conda info --envs | grep -q base ]; then echo "base already exists"; else conda create -y -n base; fi
does not work? Classic bash if statement syntax is with [] ?